# Base change of integral map by algebraic closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I'm thinking about the following problem:

Assume that $K$ is field with fixed algebraic closure $L$. Assume we have two finite field extensions $E$ and $F$ of $K$ such that $E$ is contained in $F$. Then we have an inclusion map $\iota:  E \to F$. This induces an inclusion map $\iota \otimes id: E \otimes_K L \to F \otimes_K L$. Obviously $\iota$ is an integral map but is $\iota \otimes id$ also integral?

$\textbf{Attempt on proof}$

I think I found the proof.

It suffices to show that any element of the form $f \otimes l \in F \otimes L$ is integral over $E \otimes L$. We can also assume that $l$ is not zero because otherwise it's trivial. Let $p \in E[X]$ be a polynomial such that $p(f) = 0$. We can write 
$$ p = e_0 + ... + e_n X^n$$ 
for some $e_i \in E$.
Set $a_i = e_i \otimes 1/{l^i} \in E \otimes L$. Then 
$$a_i (f \otimes l)^i = (e_i \otimes 1/{l^i})(f \otimes l)^i = (e_i \otimes 1/{l^i})(f^i \otimes l^i) = e_i f^i \otimes 1.$$
Thus we have 
$$a_0 + ... + a_n (f \otimes l)^n = (e_0 \otimes 1) +  ... _ (e_n f^n \otimes 1) = (e_0 + ... + e_n f^n) \otimes 1 = p(f) \otimes 1 = 0.$$

Comment: Yes, your proof looks fine. (You could also reason that $i \otimes Id$ is finite, and any finite map is integral.) In general, there is nothing special about the algebraic closure here. Your proof shows that if $R$ is a ring and $f \colon A \to B$ is an integral map of $R$-algebras, then for any $R$-algebra $C$, the map $f \otimes_{R} Id_{C} \colon A \otimes_{R} C \to B \otimes_{R} C$ is integral.